# when using nebular stepper (nb-stepper) in angular, onClick event on the step does not work

Tags: angular, events, click, nebular

html -

<nb-stepper orientation="horizontal" [selectedIndex]="5">
<nb-step *ngFor="let w of weeks" [label]="w" [completed]="false" (click)="doSomthing($event)">

Answer (score 1):

<nb-stepper #stepper [linear]="linearMode" (click)="stepClick($event)"> ...

Then in component:
@ViewChild('stepper') stepperComponent: NbStepperComponent;
and in the stepClick function, I have access to the stepperComponent.

https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/1308